# Correct way to add Monogame in projects

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, nuget, monogame

I would like to make a cross-platform game app with MonoGame.

The method of installing Monogame to Visual Studio [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/graphics-games/monogame/introduction/part1) didn't seem to add the option to create a cross-plat MG proj in my IDE, and though the look has changed the steps and options to creating a project are still the same. Then I went to the [documentation](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=creating_a_new_project_vs) on Monogames' website, and there was no mention of adding a Nuget package to a project, cross-plat or otherwise.<s>Is installing it the other way the only way?</s>[You can definitely use Nuget packages according to this page though.](http://www.monogame.net/downloads/)

I went into VS added them to my projects.
Right now I have both Monogame Android and iOS packages, and monogame.framework.WindowsDX installed to 3 projects in my solution (each project has .WindowsDX). Do I only add the corresponding Nuget package to Android and iOs app(that's how I have it now)?

Comment: Are the MonoGame templates showing up on Create a new project page in VS?

Comment: no, they are not, under 'Mobile App' or 'ASP.Net Core'. A search for 'mono' gives no results.

Comment: I am no longer using Monogame, as it's too buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Since Monogame is an open-source community, I prefer creating project files via Command line of dotnet rather than using Visual Studio. It's only expected that the templates might not be fully compatible in the latest edition of Visual Studio

To make the projects, first make sure that you have the NuGet template for dotnet installed by

```
dotnet new -i Monogame.CSharp.Templates
```

now, you can create your projects via dotnet new

For example, you can create a monogame android, windows and uw[ project via

```
dotnet new mgandroid
dotnet new mgwindows
dotnet new mguwp
```

You can check out other packages available via

```
dotnet new -h
```

For creating a common library for cross-platform games, I make a netstandard library and add NuGet reference to the Monogame.DesktopGL.Core library. Then, the respective platform-specific projects will be referencing this common library.

Once you are done with this, then you can create a sln in the root folder to hold all the created projects. You can do this using dotnet again by

```
dotnet new sln
```

or use Visual Studio to create a new sln and add all these projects in it.

You can check out and download my Cross-Platform Monogame Template at https://github.com/AzuxirenLeadGuy/Azuxiren.MG.Template

(I do plan to make a NuGet template out of it though in the near future)